# BigQuery Error: 33652656 | I can't directly contact Google

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been trying to connect a CSV I have in Google Drive to a BigQuery table for a week but I've been getting the following error:

"An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 33652656"

Since I have Basic Support I think I can't contact Google directly to report it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can generate a version of your sheet/CSV file that demonstrates the issue and is suitable for inclusion in a public issue tracker (e.g. any sensitive info is redacted), posting to the [BigQuery public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-support#issuetracker) may be another path forward.

Comment: Done! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217596808 Thanks for the tip.